# Identifying a Window Manufacturer

Tags: windows

I need to replace the tilt latch on this window but can't find any indication of the name of the company that manufactured the window.  I tried  a local window shop and they did not recognize it, plus they also told me the width between the two mounting screw holes is critical to finding a generic replacement part.  I'd like to start with the manufacturer if possible.  The only indication I can find is a "world" marker on the frame.  Does anyone recognize this manufacturer?
[image]

Answer (score 4):

This is without a doubt manufactured by International Window, that is their trademarked logo. I sold their windows for many years and they are quite common in S. California. Aftermarket replacement latches should be fairly easy to find:

[image]

[prime line window parts](http://www.prime-line-products.com/home4.wcs?cSearchtxt=&nMenuid=2190&cProd=F&cSProd=004&nAc=1&cAtt1=0014&cAv1=006&nPage=3)

Answer (score 0):

You could send a picture to Blane Window Hardware (http://www.blainewindow.com/index.php). They can help identify it and they have many different parts for windows. They can probably match it to an aftermarket part.